# Теряется привязка к событию при перестройке таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть календарь zabuto_calendar. К нему привязывается события наведения/ухода мыши на какую либо дату в `td`
Код:

```
$("tr.calendar-dow td").on("mousemove mouseleave", function (event){})
```

Если в календаре переключится на след. месяц, то под новый месяц заново строится строки и ячейки таблицы с такими же данными `tr.calendar-dow td`. Однако события `mousemove mouseleave` отвязываются.

Как сделать чтобы события не отпадали, или в крайнем случае при новых строк/ячеек привязывались заново ?

П.С. В календаре есть возможность вызова события по переключению месяца, однако это событие срабатывает до начала построения новых ячеек

Comment: Можно вызвать событие по переключению месяца, подожать через setinterval секунду, две и запустить прослушку `mousemove`

Comment: @Denis640Kb Спасибо, это работает, но мне кажется это некрасиво )). Но в крайнем случае, придется это юзать. Но в любом случае решает вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Помогло такое решение

```
$("table").on("mousemove mouseleave","tr.calendar-dow td", function (event) {})
```